# MPAndroidChart - How to correctly display data under their related X axis position

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to use MPAndroidChart, and I did successfully till I saw they had a new version.
Many things have changed since the version I used (following tutorial on the internet), and then I'm not able to correctly managed the display on my phone screen.

I want to display a 3 bar charts. Here are my problems:

1. The bars are not in line with their related axis spot (and they should be),
2. The 2 bars are displayed one on the other, and I would like to have them separated,
3. For the 2 "Sep", I will check my code later.

[image]

Here is what I grab into my List>:

```
Month     Loan     Borrow
7         15       5
8         0        5.7
10        102.4    2
11        15       5
12        25.5     35.5
```

Here is the code for displaying my barchart.

```
private void moneyBarChart(){
        BarChart barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        barChart.getDescription().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.money_bar_chart));
        MonthConverter monthConverter = new MonthConverter(this);
        //HorizontalBarChart barChart= (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        List<List<Float>> amountByMonth = dbHandlers.getDbMoneyHandler().getLastSixMonthsMoney();

        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> loan = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> borrow = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Float> temp = amountByMonth.get(0);
        int position = 0;
        int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int j = 5;

        barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum((float) currentMonth - j);
        barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum((float) currentMonth);

        for (int i=0; i<amountByMonth.size(); i++) {
            while (currentMonth - j != Math.round(temp.get(i * 3))-1){
                labels.add(monthConverter.convert(currentMonth - j));
                loan.add(new BarEntry(currentMonth - j, 0f));
                borrow.add(new BarEntry(currentMonth - j, 0f));
                j-=1;
                position++;
            }
            labels.add(monthConverter.convert(Math.round(temp.get(i * 3))));
            loan.add(new BarEntry(Math.round(temp.get(i * 3)-1), Math.round(temp.get(i * 3 + 1))));
            borrow.add(new BarEntry(Math.round(temp.get(i * 3)-1), Math.round(temp.get(i * 3 + 2))));
            position++;
            j-=1;
        }

        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(loan, getResources().getString(R.string.type_loan));
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
        //barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(borrow, getResources().getString(R.string.type_borrow));
        barDataSet2.setColor(Color.rgb(155, 0, 0));
        //barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataset = new ArrayList<>();
        dataset.add(barDataSet1);
        dataset.add(barDataSet2);

        //BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
        BarData data = new BarData(dataset);
        barChart.setData(data);
        barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new MonthAxisValueFormatter(barChart, this));
        barChart.invalidate();
        barChart.animateY(2000);
        barChart.getBarData().setBarWidth(0.5f);


        data.setValueFormatter(new CustomYAxisValueFormatter());
    }
```

Note sure it helps, but hereunder are the code for :

- CustomYAxisValueFormatter,
- MonthAxisValueFormatter

Here:

```
public class CustomYAxisValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public CustomYAxisValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,##0.0"); // sets precision to 1
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return mFormat.format(value);
    }
}
```

And here:

```
public class MonthAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    protected String[] mMonths;
    private Context context;

    private BarLineChartBase<?> chart;

    public MonthAxisValueFormatter(BarLineChartBase<?> chart, Context context) {
        this.chart = chart;
        this.context = context;

        mMonths = new String[]{
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.january),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.february),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.march),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.april),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.may),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.june),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.july),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.august),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.september),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.october),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.november),
                this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.december)
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

        int month = (int) value;

        String monthName = mMonths[month % mMonths.length];

        return monthName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with this: XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
xAxis.setLabelCount(12, true);

Comment: Hi Augustin, finally it allows to align my data with my X axis, thanks for that. Remains only the two bars part (red and green should be distincts bars).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this example: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivityMultiDataset.java

To see the example online:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/741#!liveDemo

You need to add lines like this:

```
float groupSpace = 0.08f;
float barSpace = 0.03f; // x4 DataSet
int groupCount = mSeekBarX.getProgress() + 1;
int startMonth = 0;
mChart.groupBars(startYear, groupSpace, barSpace);
```